# How does Distinct() work?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct

Lets say i have this:

```
class Foo
{
    public Guid id;
    public string description;
}

var list = new List<Foo>();
list.Add(new Foo() { id = Guid.Empty, description = "empty" });
list.Add(new Foo() { id = Guid.Empty, description = "empty" });
list.Add(new Foo() { id = Guid.NewGuid(), description = "notempty" });
list.Add(new Foo() { id = Guid.NewGuid(), description = "notempty2" });
```

Now, when i do this:

```
list = list.Distinct().Tolist();
```

It obviously returns 4 elements. I would like a method, that compares all the data i have in class, and returns unique elements, something that checks every property of the class. Do i need to write my own comparer, or is there something that is built-in that works this way?

Comment: You'll have to write your own comparer, or implement `IEquatable`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to override `Foo.Equals` (and subsequently `Foo.GetHashCode`) to explicitly compare each field. Otherwise it will use the default implementation, `Object.Equals` (`ReferenceEquals`).

Or, you can explicitly pass an `IEqualityComparer` to the `Distinct()` method.

---

Note though that using *anonymous classes* does return 3 elements. Depending on where you want to use `Foo` and how much compile-time type safety you need, you could do:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(new { id = Guid.Empty, description = "empty" });
list.Add(new { id = Guid.Empty, description = "empty" });
list.Add(new { id = Guid.NewGuid(), description = "notempty" });
list.Add(new { id = Guid.NewGuid(), description = "notempty2" });

list = list.Distinct().ToList(); //3 elements selected
```

Comment: I would suggest going the `IEqualityComparer` route. It's much easier to extend a class to be "equal" under different contexts in this way than it would be if you were to override the `Equals` method.

Answer (score 6):

It compares each two items using [EqualityComparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) until [specified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) another implementation of [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)