# List Distinct is not working in LINQ instead of GroupBy

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

Thanks in advance. I can get required output when using **var** but i want to get required output by using **Distinct in List<>**.

InventoryDetails.cs

```
public class InventoryDetails
{
        public int? PersonalInventoryGroupId { get; set; }
        public int? PersonalInventoryBinId { get; set; }
}
```

InventoryController.cs

```
[HttpGet("GetInventory")]
public IActionResult GetInventory(int id)
{
    //Below code will return distinct record
    var inventory = (from i in _context.TempTbl
                      where i.TempId == id
                      select new
                      {
                          PersonalInventoryBinId = i.PersonalInventoryBinId,
                          PersonalInventoryGroupId = i.PersonalInventoryGroupId,
                      }).ToList().Distinct().ToList();

    //Below code is not doing distinct
    List<InventoryDetails> inventory = (from i in _context.TempTbl
                  where i.TempId == id
                  select new InventoryDetails
                  {
                      PersonalInventoryBinId = i.PersonalInventoryBinId,
                      PersonalInventoryGroupId = i.PersonalInventoryGroupId,
                  }).ToList().Distinct().ToList();
}
```

If i use var as return type, then i am able to get distinct records. Could some one assist it.

Comment: How is the method `.Equals` of `InventoryDetails` implemented? You may want to implement it, for Distinct to work properly. Check out how Distinct works here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423632/how-does-distinct-work

Comment: I dont want to use var return type, it should be in List<InventoryDetails>

Comment: I didn't say anything about var. I only asked how is the method  `.Equals`  of `InventoryDetails` implemented. If you didn't override it, you should

Comment: I didnt override it. I am trying to get record from dbcontext with distinct

Comment: Remove the first `.ToList()` (before `Distinct()`) and you'll get `DISTINCT` applied at SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this it may help.

```
IList<InventoryDetails> inventory = _context.InventoryDetails.Where(x=>x.TempId == id).GroupBy(p => new {p.PersonalInventoryGroupId, p.PersonalInventoryBinId } )
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: When i am using your code, it is throwing casting exception from view model to table model

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework then this code should work and _context should be your db contaxt.

Comment: Yes i am using entity framework only, you didn't mention about selection

Comment: try replace "TempTbl" with "InventoryDetails" like this
_context.InventoryDetails.Where(x=>x.TempId == id).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: I've edit the answer it should work now, Try it please, if it is resolving your problem then i have another better way to achieve it.

Comment: No, it is not distinct it

Comment: which field you want to distinct? Like which column of your table should be distinct?

Comment: Both field i want to distinct

Comment: Actually, i dont want to use GroupBy

Comment: Then you can use DistinctBy property, Let me edit my answer

Comment: I dont have DistinctBy property, do i want to add system.core.dll assembly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138534/discussion-between-venkateswaran-r-and-ammar-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. 
First, let's see the AnonymousType vs InventoryDetails

```
        var AnonymousTypeObj1 = new { PersonalInventoryGroupId = 1, PersonalInventoryBinId = 1 };
        var AnonymousTypeObj2 = new { PersonalInventoryGroupId = 1, PersonalInventoryBinId = 1 };

        Console.WriteLine(AnonymousTypeObj1.Equals(AnonymousTypeObj2)); // True

        var InventoryDetailsObj1 = new InventoryDetails { PersonalInventoryBinId = 1, PersonalInventoryGroupId = 1 };
        var InvertoryDetailsObj2 = new InventoryDetails { PersonalInventoryBinId = 1, PersonalInventoryGroupId = 1 };

        Console.WriteLine(InventoryDetailsObj1.Equals(InvertoryDetailsObj2)); // False
```

You can see the Equals behave differently which make `Distinct` behave differently. The problem is not `var` you mentioned in your question but AnonoymizeType

To make `Distinct` works as you expect, you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

```
    public class InventoryDetails
    {
        public int? PersonalInventoryGroupId { get; set; }
        public int? PersonalInventoryBinId { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {

            if (obj == null) return false;

            if (obj is InventoryDetails)
            {
                if (PersonalInventoryGroupId == (obj as InventoryDetails).PersonalInventoryGroupId 
                    && PersonalInventoryBinId == (obj as InventoryDetails).PersonalInventoryBinId)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + PersonalInventoryBinId.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + PersonalInventoryGroupId.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i dont want to test whether fetched record is having duplicate or not. I want to remove duplicate record from my list without groupby. That is my requirement.

Comment: have updated my answer, you also need to override `GetHashCode()`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be

```
 List<InventoryDetails> inventory = (from i in TempTbl
                                             where i.TempId == id
                                             select new InventoryDetails
                                             {                                                   
                                                 PersonalInventoryBinId = i.PersonalInventoryBinId,
                                                 PersonalInventoryGroupId = i.PersonalInventoryGroupId,
                                             }).AsQueryable().ToList().Distinct(new customComparer()).ToList();

 public class customComparer:IEqualityComparer<InventoryDetails>
{
    public bool Equals(InventoryDetails x, InventoryDetails y)
    {
        if (x.TempId == y.TempId && x.PersonalInventoryBinId == y.PersonalInventoryBinId 
            && x.PersonalInventoryGroupId == y.PersonalInventoryGroupId)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(InventoryDetails obj)
    {
        return string.Concat(obj.PersonalInventoryBinId.ToString(),
                            obj.PersonalInventoryGroupId.ToString(),
                            obj.TempId.ToString()).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in a comment by Ivan, you make your life difficult by calling `ToList` before `Distinct`. This prevents the SQL provider from incorporating the `Distinct` call into the generated SQL statement. But that leaves the question: what causes the difference?

The first query generates anonymous type instances. As per [the C# specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12124463/861716), by default anonymous types (in C#) are equal when their properties and property values are equal (*structural equality*). Conversely, by default, reference types (like `InventoryDetails`) are equal when their reference (say memory address) is equal (*reference equality* or *identity*). They can be *made* equal by overriding their `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods, as some people suggested to do.

But that's not necessary if you remove the first `ToList()`:

```
var inventory = (from i in _context.TempTbl
    where i.TempId == id
    select new InventoryDetails
    {
        PersonalInventoryBinId = i.PersonalInventoryBinId,
        PersonalInventoryGroupId = i.PersonalInventoryGroupId,
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now the whole statement until `ToList()` is an `IQueryable` that can be translated into SQL. The SQL is executed and the database returns a distinct result set of raw records from which EF materializes `InventoryDetails` objects. The C# runtime code was even never aware of duplicates!