# Why Linq Distinct() does not work for my ConsultantList?

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, distinct

I've tried to return distinct values in my ConsultantList, but it is still returning duplicates.

```
ConsultantList = p.ProjectExtensions
       .SelectMany(pext => pext.Consultants)
       .Distinct()
       .Select(c =>
             new ConsultantItemDTO
             {
                EmployeeId = c.ConsultantId,
                EmployeeName = c.Employee.Firstname + " " + c.Employee.Lastname
             }),
```

Here is the entire method:

[Get Project Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyBHx.png)

Comment: Because you din´t provide any code nor any exception nor **anyting** we could work with. Honestly please be so kind to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `Distinct` will use the default equality comparer for the type to determine which items are unique. If you didn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the `Consultant` class (or whichever type is contained in the collection you're calling `Distinct` on), then the default comparer will be a reference comparison, which is not what you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423632/how-does-distinct-work).

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1):

**If you want to return distinct elements from sequences of objects of some custom data type, you have to implement the IEquatable generic interface in the class.**

Or you can extend the IEnumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
.Select(p => p.Employee)
.DistinctBy(p => p.EmployeeId)
```